# Keyframe animations are not working on iOS 8.x

Tags: ios, ios8

I am trying to use keyframe animations to fade in out series of views. But it does not seem to work on iOS 8. The relative start delays are not working as expected and it seems to fire some time earlier than expected. But on iOS 9 it works perfectly.

I thought it was something to do with the way I had set up the views, but turns out it does not work at all in iOS 8. There must be something wrong that I am doing.

I have below sample code to test:

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.CalculationModeLinear, animations: {

            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.25, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.redView.alpha = 0.0
            })

            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.75, relativeDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                self.blueView.alpha = 1.0
            })

            }, completion: nil)
```

So the total duration is set for 2s and each view will fade in/out with 0.5s animation duration and 0.5s delay.

But this is not working on iOS 8.x

Any help would be much appreciated !

Comment: You can slow the animation in Simulator. It's just a suggestion.

Comment: @Lumialxk Yes I did try that, it seems to not respect the relative start time.